# can we make printf align values on decimal point?

Tags: alignment, printf, string-formatting

I've encountered an array of floating point values that I can't make print out in a reasonable way with the old tried and true printf() function. The problem, I guess, is that the range of numbers is huge... from tiny numbers like -3.66542e-296 to +9.5543e+301 and lots of values in between.

Normally values are more related to each other and something like %23.16f will work. But with these huge numbers the f specifier doesn't work, because some numbers print out dozens to hundreds of digits (overflowing the size specification). This leaves the e format (or the g format which lets printf() switch back and forth between e and f formats).

When forced to adopt e or g specifier due to large range of values, is there any way to:

1. make the decimal points of all values align over each other.
2. make the e (of the exponent) of all values align over each other.
3. make the number of digits following the e be fixed (always the same).

For almost any purposes, #1 is the best option - alignment with the . is most often helpful.  But it seems impossible to make nice neat, readable columns in any way whatsoever in this situation... unless I'm missing something.